# Xcode replacing setting and spotlight icons

Tags: xcode, cordova, icons, spotlight

How do you replace the spotlight and setting icons on my app in xcode? When I install the app on my iPhone it still shows the default Cordova icons. I'm able to replace the launcher icons and splash screens but can't seem to figure out the other 2. Thanks for the help.

Comment: checkout my answer below. I guess this is what u were actually looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood it right, you are talking about buttons inside your app. If its a button, you can change the image as shown in the image below. You question is not very clear so provide more info if you meant something else.

[image]

Update: I use this free tool for icons. http://appicontemplate.com/ios7 to make my icons which gives me all sizes i need. I add all files to my project image assets. you can add the file names as shown in the apple document.

[image]

Comment: Sorry about that. When you type something into Spotlight on an iphone there are some small icons next to the app's name, its a 29x29 icon, how do you change that one out?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can not change that. It shows the resized version of your app icon.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can... Its on Apple's iOS Developer Library as it being something that can be changed. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: I stand corrected. Please see the update. Once you have these files you can add it as shown in figure 3 in apples documents.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** 
Click [image] on the left panel

**Step 2:**
Click AppIcon

**Step 3:** Click attributes inspector on the right and check the following :

[image]

**Step 4:** Hurray !! You will see options to add Spotlight and Settings icons on the main window :

[image]